# Solve $y^2 = x^3+1$ in integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

It is proven that $\sqrt{x^3 +1}$ is a integer with $x$ equal to some three integral values.

I found $0$ and $2$. By trial and error. Is there a smarter way.

Comment: By observation, $-1$ is too.

Comment: Finding $3$ solutions by trial and error is not hard. What is not obvious is that these are the **only** solutions. One can show that $y^2=x^3+1$ has no integer solutions other than $x=-1$, $x=0$, and $x=2$, but this takes a while.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. We want $\sqrt{x^3+1}$ to be an integer $y$. So we want $y^2=x^3+1$. Putting $y=0$ gives $x^3=-1$, so $x=-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are some things you can say. Call $c$ the integer you're talking about. You have $x^3 = (c-1)(c+1)$. Necessarily, the Bezout identity gives you that the gcd of $c-1$ and $c+1$ divides 2, so it is 1 or 2: $1\times(c+1) - 1\times(c-1) =2$.

If the gcd is 1, you need both $(c-1)$ and $(c+1)$ to be perfect cubes, which won't happen apart from $c+1 = 1$ and $c-1=-1$.

If the gcd is 2, $(c-1)(c+1)=4kk'$ with a gcd$(k,k')=1$ So one has to be even and the other odd, which can be rewritten $(c-1)(c+1)=8l(2m+1)$ with gcd$(l,2m+1)=1$ and both $l$ and $2m+1$ are perfect cube, so $(c-1)(c+1)=(2\alpha\beta)^3$ with gcd$(\alpha,\beta)=1$.

Any other divisor apart from 2 has to be a perfect cube and again there are no perfect cubes separated by only 2 after 0 and 1. That gives you the solution $c-1 = 2$ and $c+1 =4$.

It's a bit messy, but you have the main arguments to clarify.

Comment: +1, even though I don't know about Bezouts identity.

Comment: You should check the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity In any case, I'm using the trivial implication: if a divisor divides $a$ and $b$, it divides any linear combination, in our case 2.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing negative numbers emits the value $-1$.

An interesting problem would be to prove that there is no perfect square that immediately follows an integer cubed other than the three values: $-1,0,2$.  I did a very quick search in Mathematica up to $x=1000$ and didn't find any others (unless I somehow messed up).